# How to split up certain characters but not others?

Tags: python

I want to take an input of a string of elements and make one list with the atoms and the amount of that atom.
`["H3", "He4"]`

That sections works, however I also need to make a list of only the elements. It would look something like
`["H", "He"]`

However when I try and split it into individual atoms it comes out like.
`["H", "H", "He"]`

Here is my current code for the function:

```
def molar_mass():
    nums = "0123456789"
    print("Please use the format H3 He4")
    elements = input("Please leaves spaces between elements and their multipliers: ")
    element_list = elements.split()
    print(element_list)
    elements_only_list = []
    for element_pair in element_list:
        for char in element_pair:
            if char not in nums:
                elements_only_list.append(char)
        test = element_pair.split()
        print(test)
    print(elements_only_list)
```

I'm aware that there is a library for something similar, however I don't wish to use it.

Comment: If there's a library why don't you read the implementation in the library and try to implement your version of it?

Comment: I think you will have to create a full list of all chemical elements and split them out starting from the longest items (otherwise the script would think that you have H for Hydrogen but instead you have He for Helium, for example. If you start from Helium you cannot have the problem).

Comment: Have a look into the regex `re` library for extracting text strings.

Comment: I'm using this as an experience to learn and I'm very new.

Comment: What is your problem? You want the `elements_only_list`    list to include unique elements only? If this is the issue, try using set for `elements_only_list` Also what is the meaning of this line?    `test = element_pair.split()`

Comment: Yes, the problem arises when I try and make it only elements and no numbers. The problem is that it splits it up by letter rather then element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are appending each non-numeric character to `elements_only_list`, as a new element of that list.  You want instead to get the portion of `element_pair` that contains non-numeric characters, and append that string to the list.  A simple way to do this is to use the `rstrip` method to remove the numeric characters from the end of the string.

```
for element_pair in element_list:
  element_only = element_pair.rstrip(nums)
  elements_only_list.append(element_only)
```

It could also be done using regular expressions, but that's more complicated than you need right now.

FYI, you don't really need your `nums` variable. The `string` module contains constants for various standard groups of characters.  In this case you could import `string.digits`.

Comment: While this is indeed a nice suggestion I think that numbers can appear anywhere in a chemical formula such as H2SO4

Comment: @Pitto that's true, but based on the code provided, the program would expect that to be input with spaces between the items: H2 S O4.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, you will have user input such as H3 He4 and expect the output to be ['H','He'], accordingly i modified your function:

```
def molar_mass():


    print("Please use the format H3 He4")
    elements = input("Please leaves spaces between elements and their multipliers: ")
    element_list = elements.split() # splits text to a list
    print(element_list)


    results = []
    for elem in element_list: # loops over elements list
    
        #seperate digits from characters in a list and replace digits with ''
        el1 = list(map(lambda x: x if  not x.isdigit() else '' , elem))
        el2 = ''.join(el1) 
        results.append(el2)
return results

molar_mass()
```

using this function, with an input as below:

```
H3 He4
```

output will be:

```
['H','He']
```